# Test containers: ignore parent `EXPOSE` instruction from Dockerfile

Tags: java, scala, docker, couchbase, testcontainers

I'm trying to run Couchbase v.5.1.1 docker container for test purposes via Test container with fixed exposed ports, like:

```
trait CouchbaseTestEnvironment extends ForAllTestContainer {
  this: Suite =>

  def couchbaseContainer: FixedHostPortGenericContainer = {
    val consumer = new Slf4jLogConsumer(LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass))

    /*
     * Couchbase should know which ports are exposed for client, because this is how it exposes services.
     * E.g. client ask only for on port - say 8091. And query service port is 8093. So client, won't ask for every port,
     * instead CB will tell client on which port query service exposed, that's why CB should be aware about port mapping.
     * That's why we need to give CB port mappings
     *
     * See for more details:
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277436/couchbase-in-docker-for-integration-tests-make-the-ports-8092-8093-8094-and-8
     */

    def randomPort: Int = {
      val (from, to) = (32768, 35000) //linux private port range
      from + Random.nextInt(to - from)
    }

    val random8091Port = randomPort
    val random8092Port = randomPort
    val random8093Port = randomPort
    val random8094Port = randomPort
    val random11210Port = randomPort

    val container = FixedHostPortGenericContainer(
      imageName = "couchbase:community-5.0.1",
      exposedHostPort = random8091Port,
      exposedContainerPort = random8091Port,
      env = Map(
        "COUCHBASE_RANDOM_PORT_8091" -> random8091Port.toString,
        "COUCHBASE_RANDOM_PORT_8092" -> random8092Port.toString,
        "COUCHBASE_RANDOM_PORT_8093" -> random8093Port.toString,
        "COUCHBASE_RANDOM_PORT_8094" -> random8094Port.toString,
        "COUCHBASE_RANDOM_PORT_11210" -> random11210Port.toString
      )
    )

    container.container.withFixedExposedPort(random8092Port, random8092Port)
    container.container.withFixedExposedPort(random8093Port, random8093Port)
    container.container.withFixedExposedPort(random8094Port, random8094Port)
    container.container.withFixedExposedPort(random11210Port, random11210Port)

    container.container.withLogConsumer(consumer)

    container
  }
}
```

So as you can see 5 FIXED ports should be exposed.
But, when I'm running tests I actually can see, that instead other ports exposed with random ports:

```
docker ps

f4fc1ce06544   couchbase:community-5.0.1   "/entrypoint.sh /opt…"   59 seconds ago   Up 1 second    0.0.0.0:55264->8091/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55263->8092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55262->8093/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55261->8094/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55260->11207/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55259->11210/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55258->11211/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55257->18091/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55256->18092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55255->18093/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55254->18094/tcp   unruffled_mendel
03b491ac2ea8   testcontainersofficial/ryuk:0.3.0
```

So as you can see another ports was exposed, and mapped to random ports instead fixed.

As far as I understand, test containers, ignores ports I gave, and instead exposes ports from Couchbase Dockerfile: https://github.com/couchbase/docker/blob/master/community/couchbase-server/5.1.1/Dockerfile#L74

```
EXPOSE 8091 8092 8093 8094 8095 8096 11207 11210 11211 18091 18092 18093 18094 18095 18096
```

Can I somehow force Test containers to ignore `EXPOSE` instruction?

Partially helped question: [Couchbase in docker for integration tests: Make the ports 8092, 8093, 8094 and 8095 configurable to be able to use docker’s random ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277436/couchbase-in-docker-for-integration-tests-make-the-ports-8092-8093-8094-and-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow force Test containers to ignore EXPOSE instruction?

I don't know if there is a simple configuration option for this, but a workaround solution I found is to use an advanced feature of [the docker-java create container command customization](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/advanced_options#customizing-the-container). I'm providing an example in Java, translate it to Scala yourself, please. Apply it as the last command before returning a container object from your function:

```java
container.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(
    cmd -> cmd.getHostConfig().withPublishAllPorts(false)
);
```

The main point here is the usage of `.withPublishAllPorts(false)`. From my understanding, this is the same as `--publish-all` (or `-P`) arguments of the `docker run` command. Testcontainers library [sets](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/8965712f239ae3c449cec579264af5e79265f314/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/GenericContainer.java#L802) this value to `true` by default. This modification overrides it to `false`.

With this configuration no ports are published at all for your example, not the 5 fixed as expected:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                        NAMES
2ee4fb91b97c   couchbase:community-5.0.1   "/entrypoint.sh couc…"   33 seconds ago   Up 32 seconds   8091-8094/tcp, 11207/tcp, 11210-11211/tcp, 18091-18094/tcp   trusting_keldysh
```

This is because in the answer you provided, the author created a special custom docker image of couchbase, which "understands" environment variables like `COUCHBASE_RANDOM_PORT_8091`. Your code uses the standard couchbase image `couchbase:community-5.0.1`, which basically just ignores these environment variables. So in order to run counchbase on not standard internal ports, you need to build a custom image with the "magic" `configure-node.sh` script, which tunes couchbase config using values provided in environment variables.

I hope it helps anyhow :)

Comment: Yes, it is definitely helps! Thank you a lot for such descriptive answer.

Comment: Quick question: `custom image with the "magic"` can you suggest what kind of magic I supposed to implement? Can I override in child Dokcerfile expose instruction? Thanks

Comment: You need something which overrides the default internal ports of couchbase inside the container based on env vars. Like `sed -i "s|8092|${COUCHBASE_RANDOM_PORT_8092}|g" /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.d/capi.ini`. This should be done before starting the couchbase server.

Comment: Ok I see. Well honestly, I done this but anyway this did no help, test containers still exposes ports from parent Dockerfile. I'll try to maybe somehow override `EXPOSE` instruction from parent Dockerfile if it is possible. Thank you so much for a help once again!

Comment: I'd say `EXPOSE` is not that important. It's more like documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose I'd recommend to ssh into your custom container and make sure that couchbase is really running on the custom port inside, not on the default. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you - good point. Thanks for a help!